# How to align an image at the end of the first line of a paragraph?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code, which is very simple, just an image inside a paragraph.

```
  <p> 
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/pineapple.jpg" />
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  adipisicing elit. Minus incidunt recusandae quae molestias corporis veniam repellat provident aliquam amet odio cupiditate animi rerum neque voluptates iusto, odit. Numquam, sunt, dicta.  
  </p>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

And I want the image to "float" to the end of the first paragraph like below:

[image: Image is on first line]

The only way I was able to obtain this design is to insert the image at the end of the first line, but is it any CSS code that could do that?

My HTML solution is not generic and you have to manually place the image inside paragraph:

```
  <p> 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/pineapple.jpg" />
       adipisicing elit. Minus incidunt recusandae quae molestias corporis veniam repellat provident aliquam amet odio cupiditate animi rerum neque voluptates iusto, odit. Numquam, sunt, dicta.  
  </p>
```

Comment: You even have the word `float` in your question

Comment: That's why I have put it in quotes because it did not work for me :|

Comment: @mplungjan could you remove the association with a similar question. It's different because it has to align to the right with the first line only of the paragraph.

Comment: *the deprecated attribute "align":* --> it's deprecated and you need to use float instead

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never has.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use [align attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) for the image tag element,

I think this is what you want

```html
<p> 
    <img  align="right" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/pineapple.jpg" />
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  adipisicing elit. Minus incidunt recusandae quae molestias corporis veniam repellat provident aliquam amet odio cupiditate animi rerum neque voluptates iusto, odit. Numquam, sunt, dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  adipisicing elit. Minus incidunt recusandae quae molestias corporis veniam repellat provident aliquam amet odio cupiditate animi rerum neque voluptates iusto, odit. Numquam, sunt, dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  adipisicing elit. Minus incidunt recusandae quae molestias corporis veniam repellat provident aliquam amet odio cupiditate animi rerum neque voluptates iusto, odit. Numquam, sunt, dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  adipisicing elit. Minus incidunt recusandae quae molestias corporis veniam repellat provident aliquam amet odio cupiditate animi rerum neque voluptates iusto, odit. Numquam, sunt, dicta.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  adipisicing elit. Minus incidunt recusandae quae molestias corporis veniam repellat provident aliquam amet odio cupiditate animi rerum neque voluptates iusto, odit. Numquam, sunt, dicta.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  adipisicing elit. Minus incidunt recusandae quae molestias corporis veniam repellat provident aliquam amet odio cupiditate animi rerum neque voluptates iusto, odit. Numquam, sunt, dicta.  
 </p>
```

As per the document on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) the align attribute is deprecated, so CSS would be a better way to go:

```css
img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<p> 
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/pineapple.jpg" />
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  adipisicing elit. Minus incidunt recusandae quae molestias corporis veniam repellat provident aliquam amet odio cupiditate animi rerum neque voluptates iusto, odit. Numquam, sunt, dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  adipisicing elit. Minus incidunt recusandae quae molestias corporis veniam repellat provident aliquam amet odio cupiditate animi rerum neque voluptates iusto, odit. Numquam, sunt, dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  adipisicing elit. Minus incidunt recusandae quae molestias corporis veniam repellat provident aliquam amet odio cupiditate animi rerum neque voluptates iusto, odit. Numquam, sunt, dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  adipisicing elit. Minus incidunt recusandae quae molestias corporis veniam repellat provident aliquam amet odio cupiditate animi rerum neque voluptates iusto, odit. Numquam, sunt, dicta.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  adipisicing elit. Minus incidunt recusandae quae molestias corporis veniam repellat provident aliquam amet odio cupiditate animi rerum neque voluptates iusto, odit. Numquam, sunt, dicta.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  adipisicing elit. Minus incidunt recusandae quae molestias corporis veniam repellat provident aliquam amet odio cupiditate animi rerum neque voluptates iusto, odit. Numquam, sunt, dicta.  
 </p>
```

**Update**:

Solution combined from the answers: The idea is to align the image to the right with the deprecated attribute "align":

HTML code:

```
<div>
    <p> 
     <img align="right" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/pineapple.jpg" />
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  adipisicing elit. Minus incidunt recusandae quae molestias corporis veniam repellat provident aliquam amet odio cupiditate animi rerum neque voluptates iusto, odit. Numquam, sunt, dicta.  
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: -85px /* this allows you to put the image upper */
}

div {
  margin-top: 100px; /* gives you space above to display the image */
}
```

Comment: CSS would be preferable

Comment: I'm updating my answer, just notice that its deprecated attributes, its been ages since I used it.

Comment: Also huge dupe.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman it works with align right and then using negative top margin for image. I will post the updated solution in the question.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman Could you please modify your answer, maybe copy the solution from the question, so I can mark your answer as accepted. Also so I can remove the solution from the question.

Also very important to remove the float form CSS. From my test it did not work with float.

Comment: It's worse than deprecated. `align` has been [marked obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for years!

Comment: @Rob the "align" attribute is the only solution so far that it actually works if you need to align the image as per my client requirement. Therefore taking into account that you are using an absolute attribute, it's the only one that we know so far..

Comment: @AlinCiocan Yes but it serves as notice that browser vendors, at any time, may remove support for that without notice. I do believe there is a better solution but I don't have time to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css code..

**Css**

```css
p img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/pineapple.jpg" /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus incidunt recusandae quae molestias corporis veniam repellat provident aliquam amet odio cupiditate animi rerum neque voluptates
  iusto, odit. Numquam, sunt, dicta.
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not placing the image at the end of the first line

Comment: its working fine for me.. can u plz add ur code in codepen?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/mojiholuci/edit?html,css,output   This is the solution with align right and negative margin

Comment: @AlinCiocan would margin-top: -85px not be what you actually wanted?

Comment: You are right. I have change it with -85px. https://jsbin.com/muyaqec/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @Manikandan2811 Yes it's working, but you have to remove the "float" from CSS. For some reasons, it's not working with an image floated.

Comment: You need to change your answer, so I can upvoted or mark as accepted. Because the current version from your answer with "float" it's not ok. Maybe you could copy the solution from the question and I can remove it afterwards and mark your answer as the right one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208030/discussion-between-alin-ciocan-and-manikandan2811).

Comment: can u plz check once what css added for align="right".. both are same. if u are not possible to add in the backend.. u can add the css code directly.. align="right" means float:right and align="left" means float:left'

Comment: From my side its not possible continue in chat.. so u can send the msg from here only!!